# Where can I buy French Canadian keypad replacements for my MacBook Pro?

Tags: keyboard

I have a 2019 touchbar Macbook Pro. I want to replace the keypads with French Canadian ones.

Where can I buy French Canadian keypad replacements?

EDIT: Need to find an online way of buying them. I've been researching and asking at many sites with no success until now.

Comment: What is your current keyboard?  French Canadian has one me more than US English.

Comment: I currently have an AZERTY keyboard. But even if the layout is different, I don't really care as I'm swapping the necessary keypads and keeping the others.

Comment: AZERTY also has the extra key.  Have you considered a keyboard cover?  A  lot easier than trying to find those keys or a new keyboard.

Comment: Yes I've been considering covers but not interested.

Answer (score 2):

Any Apple Authorised Service Provider should be able to order a keycap kit for you. However, keep in mind that there are differences between some layouts beyond how the keys are labeled, so getting the exact layout might require you to replace the Top Case instead.

You can find authorised service providers at https://locate.apple.com

Comment: Thanks. I meant, online though. I have been researching and asking many sites with no success.